# Помогите пожалуйста разобраться и решить задачу основанную на работе с датами

Tags: java, дата

Прошу Вас, помочь мне разобраться в идеологии написании кода связанного со временем.

А конкретнее, если пользователь вводит  данные про день, месяц, год. И далее необходимо провести какие-то операции с этими данными, а именно отнять , добавить , и т.д. , две даты в таком формате.

Главный вопрос в том, что я не пойму какие проверки проводить допустим если мне нужно к дате 25/09/2017 добавить 12 дней. 
Или же все проверки проводить ручками, а именно, проверить, что в месяце 09, 30 дней и тогда при добавлении к 25/09/2017, 12 дней будет дата 07/10/2017, а не 06/10/2017.

А как тогда быть с февралем месяцем? (year % 4 == 0)

Также очень интересует вопрос, связанный с определением дня недели дня конкретной даты.

Вот есть задача, но с проверками корректности введенных данных ясно, а вот как проверить остальное не ясно.

> Ввести любую дату (день, месяц и год вводятся отдельно). Проверить
>   корректность введенных значений. Вывести дату следующего дня
>   (использовать стандартные встроенные классы Java вроде
>   GregorianCalendar запрещено!)

В общем, сложно мне почему-то даются вычисления связанные с датами такого формата.

Comment: Как правило в языках уже имеются классы для работы с датами. Например чтобы прибавить 12 дней будет что-то типа `Date mydate = new Date("25/09/2017"); mydate->addInterval("12d");` тоже самое с вычитанием.

Comment: Единственная проблема заключается в том, что нужно быть аккуратным именно в **вычитании** даты, например, если от 31 марта вычесть 1 месяц, то можно не попасть на февраль вовсе

Comment: Спасибо, за комментарии. Очень интересное замечание про март месяц.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 решение которое я вижу:

Пишем функцию перегона туда/сюда из Unix времени в нормальный формат и +/- обрабатываем в Unix формате предварительно заведя константы (типа 1 месяц столько-то секунд, 1 год, 1 день и т.д. - проблем с вычитанием не будет - проверять нечего)

При этом Вы должны очень аккуратно проверять ввод. Лучше попросить вводить данные в порядке: год -> месяц -> день. Что бы сразу проверять наличие 29 февраля и не просить все заного вводить.

2 решение:

заморочиться и написать самому аналог GregorianCalendar. И проверять все вручную. Опять же пересчитывая все данные - год (вис/не вис), месяц (кол-во дней), день (не выпал ли за пределы месяца)

Особенности и как считать [Григорианский календарь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C).

Что такое [UNIX-время](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F) и [как преобразовать его туда/сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432735/convert-unix-time-stamp-to-date-in-java)

Comment: Спасибо, за подсказки.

Comment: Отметьте галочкой ответ, который Вам помог.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) или [DateUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html#addDays-java.util.Date-int-) из [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/). В этих библиотеках есть готовые, нужные вам методы, манипуляции с датами. Можно обойтись и стандартным календарём, пример есть [здесь](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-date-time-date-manipulation-java/).

Comment: А ещё в Java 8 есть новый пакет [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), там тоже есть много нового и полезного для вас в вашем вопросе.

Answer (score -1):

можно взять в качестве инспирации java.time.LocalDate 
его же можно взять и для тестирования собственного кода.